# How to remove TextFormField default bottom padding in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

[image]

How can I remove the default bottom padding from the TextFormField?

I try to remove all default padding it didn't work.

```
Expanded(
    child:AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child:  Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: TextFormField(
          scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          focusNode: pin1FocusNode,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          maxLength: 1,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            counter: const Offstage(),
            contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.zero,
            border: outlineInputBorder(),
            focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder(),
            enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder(),
          ),
          onChanged: (value) => nextField(value, pinFocusNode),
        ),
      )))
```

Comment: may be it is because of the aspect ratio not textformfield

Comment: Also add isDense: true in InputDecoration

Comment: @Per.J is not work

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove this padding, you can do one thing, you can remove the underline from `TextFormField` and but border under the `container`., it may be easy. And instead of using `Expanded` and `AspectRatio` just put some height and width in the container.